# How can i add two product in cart onlclick add to cart buton?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to add two product in cart when i click the add to cart button.

I have modified the code of 'Add to cart' button. But it is adding only one product in cart.

```
<button type="button" 
title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" 
class="button btn-cart" 
onclick="setLocation(
'<?php echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($Id1,$Id2))?>'
)">
<span><span>
<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>
</span></span>
</button>
```

Only Id1 product is added in the cart.But i want id1 and id2 product both.

Answer (score 0):

the function load() has two parameters: id and field.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($Id1,$Id2)
```

this is not correct, because the second parameters is not interpreted as an ID.

You probably should make an observer on the 'checkout_cart_add_product_complete' event, but for answering your question you can simply modify your code to get it works:

declare your _ids and the _addToCart urls:

```
<?php   
    $id1 = your_1st_id;
    $id2 = ypur_2nd_id;

    $_addCart1 = (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')
    ->getAddUrl(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($id1));

    $_addCart2 = (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')
    ->getAddUrl(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($id2));
?>
```

declare the button, you will need a js function to pop-out two links with one click:

```
    <button type="button"
        title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"
        class="button btn-cart"
        onclick="pageloader();">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
    </button>
```

and the js function can be like this:

```
<script>
function pageloader()
{

    window.open("<?php echo $_addCart1; ?>", "_blank");
    window.open("<?php echo $_addCart2; ?>", '_blank');

}

</script>
```

all this code can be placed in a template.phtml file, but this in my opinion is not the correct way for doing what you are asking for.
I recommend to create an Observer and elaborate your data there.
Hope to solve your problems.